# Flutter Web DevTools CPU profiler options are missing in flutter devtools

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, devtools

[image: This CPU Flame Chart, Call Tree, Bottom-Up tabs are not being shown in my web devtools]

[![This is how Web Devtools are being shown at my end]
**Here is what I have,**

"CPU Flame Chart, Call Tree, Bottom UP" Tabs not showing up or missing
Please guide how to find these tools, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Not all tools are currently available for web. There's a table showing which are available where on the Dart website:

https://dart.dev/tools/dart-devtools

[image: Table showing which tools are available for which types of project]

Comment: but I am testing for Mobile applications not for the web, I just have installed flutter application on my mobile then clicked on open DevTools to check my app performance where I realized these tools were missing

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the title "Flutter Web" to mean running on web :) In your screenshot I can see tabs for the other tools. Are they not clickable?

Comment: I have shown top above image to just show these tabs are missing, these tabs are not being shown at my side as you can see from top below image

Comment: The top image is cropped and we can't see the top bar. Can you provide an uncropped image? Also - are you using DevTools embedded inside VS Code? If so, each page appears as its own tab - when you click DevTools in the status bar, it will ask which page you want to open.

Comment: First i took from the internet to show you what tools are not being shown to me so i have deleted that picture to avoid confusion, now this is what i have, I am using android studio and opend DevTools from android studio

Comment: In your screenshot there is a tab at the top that says "CPU Profiler". What happens when you click it (if nothing, is there a tooltip if you hover over it?)